# adb is not recognized as internal or external command on windows. I can only use adb when i am in the android sdk

Tags: android, path, adb

I get this error message

> adb is not recognized as internal or external command on windows.

I think it's something with the path but I have added the path to the environment variable. I have:

```
Variable:ANDROID_HOME

Value: C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Variable: ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

Value: C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Variable: ANDROID_HOME/tools

Value: C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools
```

Comment: Add below details with system environment.

Variable: Path

Value: C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Comment: So i should have both a user variable and a system variable?

And what sould the systemvariable be called?

Comment: No,Only system variable

Comment: Should i add all of them to system variable or just that one or?

Comment: For adb only required this : C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Comment: i have added a system variable named "ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"

with the value "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools"

it still doesnt work

Comment: Have you added with Path?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by added with path?

Comment: Once check with here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z7Ug.png

Comment: that worked! thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a variable `Path` aswell, with values separated by `;`.

This is the only variable that matters when Windows tries to find an executable without the absolute path to the file given.

For example, if your current path looks like

```
C:\Some\Folder;C:\Some\Other\Folder;D:\My\Directory
```

just add another entry to the end (or the beginning) like

```
C:\Some\Folder;C:\Some\Other\Folder;D:\My\Directory;C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

Then you should be able to find all .exe files in that `sdk` folder. Don't forget that you have to restart your command line (or whatever tool you want to use `adb` from) after editing the variables for that to take effect.

You can also reuse your existing variables in the path:

```
C:\Some\Folder;C:\Some\Other\Folder;D:\My\Directory;%ANDROID_HOME%
```

You can add new entries to the end, at the beginning or somewhere in the middle - that influences the order in which Windows checks the folders to find the exe. When there is only one folder containing your .exe, the order does not matter.

Comment: it took me some time to understand but that was the right answer so thanks a lot.